# How do you add an element into the last place inside a DIV with jQuery?

Tags: jquery

If I have a div like this:

```
<div id="a">
    <div id="a1">...</div>
    <div id="a2">...</div>
    <div id="a3">...</div>
</div>
```

How do I add another div into the last position inside `#a` using jQuery?

```
    <div id="a4">...</div>
```

so that it becomes this:

```
<div id="a">
    <div id="a1">...</div>
    <div id="a2">...</div>
    <div id="a3">...</div>
    <div id="a4">...</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 6):

Just use [`.append()`](http://api.jquery.com/append/) to stick it at the end:

```
$("#a").append('<div id="a4">...</div>');
```

If `a4` *already* exists, or you're creating it, you can also use [`.appendTo()`](http://api.jquery.com/appendTo/) the other way around:

```
$("#a4").appendTo("#a");
//or if creating...
$('<div id="a4">...</div>').appendTo("#a");
```

Answer (score 2):

try this

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-latest.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">

$( init );

function init() {
  var newPara = $( "<div id='a4'>...</div>" );
  $('#a').prepend( newPara );

}

</script>

</head>
<body>
  <div id="a">
    <div id="a1">...</div>
    <div id="a2">...</div>
    <div id="a3">...</div>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use jQuery's append method - http://api.jquery.com/append/

```
$('#a').append('<div id="a4">...</div>');
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's another alternative:

```
$("#a").append(function() {
    var nextId = $(this).children().length + 1;
    return $('<div/>')
        .attr('id','a' + nextId)
        .html('New id: a' + nextId);
});
```

This will check how many divs you have an add a new one with the correct ID

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/jonathon/2h9aZ/